# No screen session found when a screen is definitely running

Tags: php, linux, bash

G'day,

I have a detached screen running a game server and I am using a bash script  `command.sh`  to send commands to a detached screen.

In a terminal I can use the following command and the server performs the command succesfully:

```
./command.sh 'any command'
```

However once I use PHP to call the script using:

```
    <?PHP
        if($_POST) {
            $commandString = $_POST['inputCommand'];
            $output = shell_exec('./command.sh $commandString');
            echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
            }
    ?>
```

The screen returns the error:

```
No screen session found.
```

I have tried changing the permissions of the bash script to 777 and also tried putting it in the web root directory.

Does any one have any ideas as to why php cannot run the script but I can run the script in a terminal ?

---

**Additional Requested Info**

command.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
 screen -S "minecraft" -X stuff "$@"$'\015'
```

Comment: can you run a simple command like `ls`?

Comment: Through shell execute, yes. But not through the screen.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `command.sh`? Is the script running as the same user as the PHP script?

Comment: Added to the end of my post, note that this script works correctly when executed in terminal. 
I don't understand how to tell what user PHP is executing the file as. Is there a default user it uses?

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and a *serious security risk.*** If you have had a world-writable script on an internet-facing server for any amount of time, you absolutely want to check whether this has been abused to penetrate your network security.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to start php script from Web-Server with another user (by default www-data).

To send some text to a screen you have to run the command as the screen owner because of 700 permission of screen in /var/run/screen/S-user/

Please try to change your string:

```
sudo -u owner_of_the_screen ./command.sh $commandString
```

Comment: Added www-data to sudoers and tried your string, it does not work.